# Windows Phone C# setSource VideoBrush from a different class file to MainPage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="Bank.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WPCordovaClassLib;assembly=WPCordovaClassLib"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="false">
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>          
    <Image x:Name="splashImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="SplashScreen.png" ImageOpened="OnImageOpened" Opacity="1"></Image>
       <my:CordovaView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
               Margin="0,0,0,0"  
               x:Name="CordovaView" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" StartPageUri="/www/default/index.html" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>

    <Canvas Name="canvasBrush" Width="640" Height="480" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <!--Camera viewfinder -->
        <Canvas.Background>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="cameraBrush" SourceName="cam"/>
        </Canvas.Background>
      </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

i want to setSource to VideoBrush from **appdataInterface.cs** and the code is as below

```
 public class cameraCustom : BaseCommand
{
    public void camera(string arg)
    {
        PhotoCamera cam;
        if ((PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary) == true) ||
                 (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing) == true))
        {
            // Initialize the camera, when available.
            if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing))
            {
                // Use front-facing camera if available.
                cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.FrontFacing);
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, use standard camera on back of phone.
                cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
            }

            // Event is fired when the PhotoCamera object has been initialized.
            cam.Initialized += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Devices.CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(cam_Initialized);

            // Event is fired when the capture sequence is complete.
            cam.CaptureCompleted += new EventHandler<CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(cam_CaptureCompleted);

            // Event is fired when the capture sequence is complete and an image is available.
            cam.CaptureImageAvailable += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs>(cam_CaptureImageAvailable);

            // Event is fired when the capture sequence is complete and a thumbnail image is available.
            cam.CaptureThumbnailAvailable += new EventHandler<ContentReadyEventArgs>(cam_CaptureThumbnailAvailable);

            //Set the VideoBrush source to the camera.
            Bank.MainPage view = new Bank.MainPage();

            view.LayoutRoot.FindName("cameraBrush");
        }
    }
}
```

i want to set

```
cameraBrush.SetSource(cam);
```

from **appdataInterface.cs**.
 How should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you shouldn't be able to that that easily.
Pass `MainPage` to `appdataInterface.cs` and you can then call a method on `MainPage` that will actually set the brush:

```
// MainPage.xaml.cs
public void SetBrush(VideoBrush brush)
{
    cameraBrush = brush;
}


// appdataInterface.cs
public appdataInterface(MainPage page)
{
    _page = page;
}

// later on
_page.SetBrush(videoBrush);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will pass you'r MainPage instance to the appdataInterface.cs it should work as you want.

When you initialize your class, something like:

appdataInterface AI = new appdataInterface();
AI.Main=this;

In appdataInterface.cs you should have:

public MainPage Main {get;set;}

And on the MainPage.xaml.cs you should have cameraBrush - as a global public, then you can do this from you'r class:

Main.cameraBrush.SetSource(cam);